# Adding webpart to page using javascript - which permissions are needed?

Tags: javascript, web-part, permissions

So I have a script up and running for the users easily to add a predefined webpart to a page (Like described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185010(v=office.14)#adding-a-web-part-to-a-page-using-javascript)) - now it would seem my users havn't got access to actually execute the script. I have tried several different permission level with no success - eventually I tried Full Control, but that didn't work either for my users. For me as a collection admin it works every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah made a silly mistake - I granted permission on the sub site to add webparts, but the users didn't have access to use external interfaces (Which I suspect is needed) on the site where the javascript was running.